# How to add network to brownie-config.yaml

Tags: ganache, brownie

I know you can add a network to brownie by using a command:

```
brownie networks add Ethereum ganache-local host=http://127.0.0.1:7545 chainid=5777
```

or for example:

```
brownie networks add development ganache-local host=http://127.0.0.1:7545 cmd=ganache
```

In both cases, I get a network named `ganache-local` that is connected to my ganache GUI and therefore I can deploy my smart contracts and do testing there.

However, what I want, is to know how to add network into `brownie-confing.yaml` file and have it work all the same. (As I am well used to doing that inside truffle-config.js)

I tried it in a few ways, but nothing worked so far.
Here is my brownie-config.yaml. Hopefully, someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. (I am trying to add a network named `local` that has the same parameters as the `ganache-local` from the commands listed above.

```
networks:
  local: # the default network that brownie connects to
    host: "127.0.0.1"
    port: 7545
    chainid: 5777
    network_id: "*"
    cmd: ganache

compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.2"
```

Whenever I try running: `brownie run deploy.py --network local`

I get an error: *`KeyError: 'local'`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add your network configuration inside `.brownie/network-config.yaml` NOT inside `brownie-confing.yaml`

Unlike truffle, where network configurations are inside `truffle-config.js`
Brownie holds them inside `network-config.yaml`

I managed to set up new network just by adding this to the end of the `network-config.yaml`

```
 - name: Ganache-GUI
    chainid: 5777
    id: ganache-local
    host: http://localhost:7545
```

Simple as that.

Comment: I have some similar kind of issue. I tried with .brownie/netowrk-config.yaml. It also gave me same error.Can you look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/139017/brownie-not-reading-account-private-key-from-cinfiguration-file

Answer (score 1):

- This is how I added `sepolia`.

```sh
brownie networks add Ethereum sepolia host="https://rpc.sepolia.org/" chainid=11155111
```

- Local testing

```py
brownie networks add Ethereum local host=http://127.0.0.1:8545 chainid=1337
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here, I also had issues adding Sepolia to brownie but now it works: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/149826/97043

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/88845)