# Infura network support for sepollia in Brownie

Tags: infura, chainlink, brownie, goerli, sepolia

I have been trying to get testnet LINK for Goerli from chain.link.  But it looks like it is no longer providing that for Goerli but Sepolia only.  I am using the latest version of Brownie and it only has Goerli for Infura.  So can you add manually Sepolia into the Brownie supported networks.  On [infura.io](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ethereum/how-to/choose-a-network) site, there is some info on network and URL.

Output from brownie networks list command:

Ethereum

Mainnet (Infura): mainnet

Ropsten (Infura): ropsten

Rinkeby (Infura): rinkeby

Goerli (Infura): goerli

Kovan (Infura): kovan

ganache-local: ganache-local

From [infuro.io](https://docs.infura.io/infura/networks/ethereum/how-to/choose-a-network):

Network Description         URL

Sepolia     JSON-RPC over HTTPS     https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/YOUR-API-KEY

Sepolia     JSON-RPC over WebSocket wss://sepolia.infura.io/ws/v3/YOUR-API-KEY

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Use this command in the terminal

```
brownie networks add Ethereum sepolia host="https://rpc.sepolia.dev" chainid=11155111
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `.brownie\network-config` file:

Put this code into the section where other Infura networks are located.

```
  - chainid: 11155111
    explorer: https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api
    host: https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID
    id: sepolia
    multicall2: '0x5BA1e12693Dc8F9c48aAD8770482f4739bEeD696'
    name: Sepolia (Infura)
    provider: infura
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this command in the terminal

```
networks add Ethereum sepolia host="https://rpc.sepolia.org/" chainid=11155111
```

If following host is not working try changing the rpc host you can find hosts from this site : https://sepolia.dev/

Answer (score 0):

brownie networks add Ethereum sepolia host=https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID chainid=11155111 multicall2='0x5BA1e12693Dc8F9c48aAD8770482f4739bEeD696' explorer=https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api name="Sepolia (Infura)"

Comment: How does it answer the question ?

Answer (score 0):

### [SOLVED]

NEW ---

Adding the network to Brownie at the bottom works well, just make sure:

- in .env you have a variable called "WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID"
- you do not overwrite the host in brownie-config.yaml.

Here is what I have in my brownie config for sepolia:
sepolia:
explorer: https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api
keyhash(genesis hash): "0x25a5cc106eea7138acab33231d7160d69cb777ee0c2c553fcddf5138993e6dd9"
eth_usd_price_feed: '0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306'

### OLD

Any News on this ? I'm trying to add Sepolia as well to Brownie networks but keep getting "HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: [https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/"](https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/%22) error.

I'm running the following command to add Sepolia to Brownie networks, and I do have the right WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID set in my brownie-config.yaml.

brownie networks add Ethereum sepolia host=https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID
chainid=11155111
multicall2='0x5BA1e12693Dc8F9c48aAD8770482f4739bEeD696'
explorer=https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api name="Sepolia (Infura)"

Answer (score 0):

To add to the top upvoted answer, you can view all of the supported networks by typing `brownie networks list`.

The output you see comes from the [network-config.yaml](https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/blob/master/brownie/data/network-config.yaml) file located at `~/USERNAME/.brownie/network-config.yaml`. If you add the following code to the `network-config.yaml` file and save it, you should see sepolia in the networks list:

```
- name: Sepolia (Infura)
  chainid: 11155111
  explorer: https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api
  host: https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID
  id: sepolia
  multicall2: '0x5BA1e12693Dc8F9c48aAD8770482f4739bEeD696'
  provider: infura
```

To make sepolia the default chain that is used for your project, you can create a `brownie-config.yaml` file at the root of your project and set the default to sepolia.

```
networks:
    default: sepolia
```

- [Networks documentation](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/network-management.html)
- [Network config documentation](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#networks)